# Text background behind an arrow

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

I have an arrow in Visio 2010 with text. But white box around text shut off the arrow itself. I could move a text a little further away from an arrow but I don't want to. How can I set transparent text background?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These screenshots below are for **Visio 2007**, but the instructions should be similar for **Visio 2010**.

Let's start by recreating the problem: the white background behind the text on the line

[image]

Right-click on the arrow and select **Format** / **Text**

[image]

This will launch the **Text** dialog. Under the **Text Block** tab look at the options for **Text background**. You'll notice that it is set to **Solid color**.

[image]

Now just set it to *None* and click *OK*

[image]

And now you'll see text background is no longer there

[image]

Of course, the text can still cover the line or an arrow, but at least the background is gone.