# Transparent text background in an arrow in Visio

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

I'm creating a Visio 2013 diagram, and when I add a background colour to the diagram, the text of the arrow looks like this:

[image: black arrow (on blue background) with black text (on a white rectangular background) overlaid]

I want to remove that white text background, but I can't find how...

I found the solution for Visio 2007 in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/321028/text-background-behind-an-arrow), but it doesn't work for Visio 2013, since there's no “Format” → “Text” menu. There's a “Format Shape” menu instead, but it contains only “Fill” and “Line”, no “Text”!

I tried to change the “Line” colour, and it changes the colour of the line (now is black), but I tried to change the “Fill” colour and it doen't change anything!

Answer (score 97, accepted):

It's in the extended Font/Text properties, under **Text Block**:

[image]

[Image source](http://win8rants.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/text-block-background-color-in-visio-2013/)

Comment: Thanks very much! I searched evrywhere but there... they couldn't hide it better :)

Comment: Yeah I find in general with the ribbon interface(s), if you can't find it, it's buried under one of those little arrows. :)

Comment: I would never have found this on my own. Awesome, thanks!

Comment: I wish Visio would put this where it obviously belongs (i.e. right clicking the text)

Comment: Works in Office 365 as well as of today. Also submitted feedback to Microsoft that this is too hard to find.

Comment: If you're adjusting this using VBA, you can modify the connector object's shape sheet directly. With `vsoConnector` as a `Visio.Shape`, setting the background to transparent would be: `vsoConnector.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowText, visTxtBlkBkgnd).FormulaU = "0"`

Comment: @techie007 Is there anyway to have a small halo around the text ... diagram has the text and the underlying arrow in the same colour. Transparent merges the text and line together.

Comment: Keep Solid Color to WHITE -- you would see the text along with the line like >----this way--->